# How does one approach the $n$-body problem in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, computational-physics, three-body-problem

I would like to know how does one set up and (numerically) solve the equations of motion for a system of $n$ particles interacting gravitationally in the context of general relativity. I know that one uses the geodesic equation and a metric obtained from Einstein's field equation. But how does one do that?

Comment: With great difficulty.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510284/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic, that question asks how to include special relativistic into an $n$-body simulation, while this question asks how to include general relativistic effects in the $n$-body problem. These are surely related, but subtly different. The correct answer to the linked question should talk about formulating the 1-post-Minkoskian n-body hamiltonian, while this question could suffice with an answer based on the post-Newtonian expansion.

Comment: This would be a better duplicate link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12679/

Comment: @mmeent: Done .

Comment: On does _not_.  One backs away slowly . . .